# How to copy Text value to Lookup field

Tags: lookup

I have a Master Zipcode object which has the Zipcode information. Master zipcode object has a lookup in the Account object. My requirement is I need to copy the Account object Zipcode to Master Object Zipcode lookup so that using formula field I can pull some information from the Master Zipcode object. Can any one suggest me how I can do this without Trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Without a trigger, you won't be able to since you'll need the corresponding record id, which would require a lookup soql statement `[SELECT Id FROM MasterZipCode__c WHERE Name = :myAccount.BillingPostalCode]`

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the reply. I have a trigger to do this but my client are not in favor of any code. So I am looking for option other then any custom code.

Comment: The only non-code option (to my knowledge) would be to force them to populate the lookup field on insert/edit...